# MYSQL Query count where multiple dates

Tags: mysql

I have a tool we developed that scans people via RFID as they walk into a room.

So I have datatable of scans of a person for a task setup like this

```
ID | User | Created_At 
Int| Int  | Datetime
10 | 223  | 2015-09-07 00:00:00 
etc...
```

I would like a query to see the number of unique Dates of scanning a pass each User has.

In a perfect world it would be just 3 columns in the report

ID of person and the number of distinct days they have scanned and the amount of times they scanned total.

The total scans is simple but I am getting stumped on the distinct day counts.

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a resultset showing what days each user appeared in the database.

```
           SELECT DISTINCT DATE(Created_At) Scandate, User
             FROM Scan
```

Then you aggregate that.

```
   SELECT COUNT(*) Datecount, User
     FROM (
           SELECT DISTINCT DATE(Created_At) Scandate, User
             FROM Scan
          ) A
    GROUP BY User
```

This gets you the number of dates each user appeared.

Then you need to figure out the basic counts.

```
   SELECT COUNT(*) Scancount, User
     FROM Scan
    GROUP BY User
```

Finally, you need to join these two together on User, and order them so they make sense.

```
SELECT Q.User, R.Scancount, S.Datecount
  FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(*) Datecount, User
          FROM (
                  SELECT DISTINCT DATE(Created_At) Scandate, User
                    FROM Scan
               ) A
         GROUP BY User
       ) R
  JOIN (
         SELECT COUNT(*) Scancount, User
           FROM Scan
          GROUP BY User
       ) S ON R.User = S.User
 ORDER BY Q.User
```